# How should we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

The name of [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17392/emacs) is currently just "Emacs". How should we name it?

Comment: Dang, I can't help it. I'm just up voting every option.

Comment: Now proposing a rename, since nobody is currently using it: https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/488/591

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We could call it `*scratch*`, perhaps.

Comment: Or "Scratch Buffer".

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I think legoscia was going for a pun: *Chat* is French for *cat*.  Cats scratch.

Comment: @Drew I suspect you're overthinking it. :-)

Comment: This or @FaheemMitha's.

Answer (score 12):

`*Messages*`, obviously.

(Or `*chat*`, but it feels too redundant.)

Answer (score 7):

`M-x chat` would be my suggestion. But something less obvious may be better...

Comment: +1 If the question is about what to put as the name of the link leading to it, then `Chat` is what people will look for and recognize. I guess the actual destination of that link could (also) have a cute, Emacs-specific name, but users should be able to look for "chat" and find that destination.

Answer (score 3):

`chat-mode` would be nice too, especially if we can throw it somewhere on the screen that looks like the modeline.

Answer (score 0):

`*scratch*` is more of a hidden name, in my opinion. I missed it when I was looking for the Emacs chat room and I created another one. May I suggest changing it to something more obvious?

I think Wooble's idea of `M-x chat` is a good one.

Comment: This answer looks more like a comment to me, rather than an answer. Also, if you search for "Emacs" on chat.SE, it will still find the actual room because 'Emacs' is in the room description, as a part of the site link.