# Scratch the chatroom name, change it to Emacs Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

### Problem: chat is empty

The main chat for the site frequently freezes due to infrequent usage.

I want more people to use it.

But I think the name is the source of the problem.

Looking the room up is always an exercise in frustration for me.

Ways I find a specific chat room here:

- type in a memorable substring including the name (e.g. "tavern") in the address bar and get it from my history,
- find mention of activity in the sidebar,
- join all my favorite rooms, and look for the name listed on the side.

I don't think "scratch" when I want "emacs". The default text in the `*scratch*` buffer says:

> ;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.
>   ;; To create a file, visit it with C-x C-f and enter text in its
>   buffer.

I'm looking for "Emacs". The room is named after a buffer we put junk into. That buffer is always there (by default), and users learn to ignore it.

Naming is hard. The following Q&A decided to make the name of the Emacs room, `*scratch*`: [How should we name our chat room?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-should-we-name-our-chat-room)

### Can we please change the name?

This name is clever. This name is fun.

But this is a bad name because it's not working, and I suspect it's not working because other users have the same experience that I do. To me, the asterisks say "ignore". The word "scratch" screams "ignore".

I propose a rename: ***"Emacs Chat"***. It's clear. It says exactly what it is and what we do there.

#### What about the stakeholders?

legoscia, the one who proposed the name three years ago, is never there. Neither are the other voters (by my count). But I am. I don't live there, but I lurk there most days. And I think we'll get *more* stakeholders with better branding.

I don't think the current name is working.

What do you think?

Comment: My own reason for not coming to the chat here, is that I use IRC. Finding the chat room was never a problem for me (there's a "chat" link available via the menu "hamburger" button, located top right). It doesn't mean you shouldn't change the name of course.

Comment: I've never had a problem finding it. I don't use it because whenever I've been there it's empty. Perhaps it's empty because our community is too small to support unstructured real-time chat. Or maybe IRC already fills that niche, and another chat room would just dilute a small group even further. That said, there's nothing to lose by trying a name change. We can't make it any more empty.

Comment: I don't really use the chat room here or anywhere on SE. But I tend to agree that the "cute" name `*scratch*` doesn't exactly advertise that it is the chat room for emacs.SE.

Comment: The fix for an empty chatroom is people in the chatroom. As an emacs-ism, I actually like *scratch*.

Comment: I'm not really active on the chat room since I use IRC a lot more than SO chat. If the name is an issue, perhaps we can make it prominently visible either on emacs.SE info pages or documentation pages?

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in Chat, I think

```
Emacs: *scratch*
```

would be a reasonable compromise, since you think that the word Emacs should be included in the room name.

Comment: Feels very old-timey, but if that can be an acceptable compromise between the most active chatter and the rest of the community, I'm for it.